# How to install backintime (Archlinux)

Tags: arch-linux

I'm new to Archlinux (I use it for about 16 hours) and want to install backintime to restore my old files. But I can't find backintime as a package. How can I install it (without configure and make manually)?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I solved the problem myself.

This is what I've done:

1) Go to http://aur.archlinux.org

2) Search for "backintime"

3) Click on the first link

4) Download tarball

5) unzip tarball archive

6) makepkg -s

7) pacman -U <*pkg.tar.xz>

That's all.1.2.

Comment: ArchLinux now requires a PGP Key. You need to import my key once before you can build BackInTime. Just run `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 615F366D944B4826` after `5)`. Disclaimer: I'm member of BIT Dev-Team